# C - Simple Linked List program that handles strings

Tags: c, linked-list, iteration, c-strings

The program specifications are pretty simple, just read in an input file of words and create a linked list where each node contains an entire string.

Here's my node struct:

```
typedef struct wordNode{
    char *word;
    token_type type;

    struct wordNode *next;
} wordNode;
```

The token type will come into play later after I get the LL basics working.

The general process of main is to open the input file, set up head with the first word, then iterate through the rest of the input file using a second node pointer, "current". Afterwards, print the list from the head pointer with a print list function.

```
void printList(wordNode *head)
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", head->word);
        head = head->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    //Open input file
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char nextWord[12] = "";

    //Scan in first word for head node
    fscanf(input, "%s", nextWord);

    //create head, fill it in with the first word, and create current
    wordNode *head = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
    head->word = nextWord;

    printf("%s ", head->word);
    wordNode *current = head->next;

//Begin Iteration
    while(fscanf(input, "%s", nextWord) != EOF)
    {
        current = (wordNode*)malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
        current->word = nextWord;
        current->next = NULL;
        printf("%s ", current->word);
        current = current->next;
   }

    printList(head);
 }
```

Together, those printfs within main will give me the output I want, so the strings seem to be being saved properly during the iteration, But the output given by the printList function is the last word in the list repeated a couple times followed by garbage values.

I'm thinking head is tied to current in some way and doesn't stay put at the beginning of the list through the iteration, but I'm not sure how or why its moving.

Also, should I use strcpy for saving the strings to the nodes? I tried earlier but it was leading to crashes when I tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for the `char *`s:

```
int main()
{
//Open input file
FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
char nextWord[12] = "";

//Scan in first word for head node
fscanf(input, "%s", nextWord);

//create head, fill it in with the first word, and create current
wordNode *head = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
head->next = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
head->word = (char *)calloc(strlen(nextWord) + 1);
strcpy(head->word, nextWord);

printf("%s ", head->word);
wordNode *current = head->next;

//Begin Iteration
while(fscanf(input, "%s", nextWord) != EOF)
{
    current = (wordNode*)malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
    current->word = (char *)calloc(strlen(nextWord) + 1);
    strcpy(current->word, nextWord);
    current->next = NULL;
    printf("%s ", current->word);
        current = current->next;
    }

printList(head);
}
```

Comment: `head->word = (char *)calloc(strlen(nextWord) + 1);
head->word = nextWord;` You should strcpy(), not re-assign the pointer.

Comment: @wildplasser - amended now

Answer (score 1):

`nextWord` should either be a much larger array (e.g. `nextWord[200]`) or you should limit the number of characters stored by `fscanf`, e.g.

```
fscanf(input, "%11s", nextWord);
```

Or use a larger array and limit the number of characters.

You need to make a copy of each string after reading it into the `nextWord` array. The code currently just assigns the address of the `nextWord` array to each `word` pointer. So every node in the linked list points to the same string, which will be the last string read from the file. To copy a string, you need to allocate memory and then `strcpy`. The `strdup` function will do that for you, but `strdup` is not supported on all systems.

When the code creates the `head` it allocates memory for two structures. Instead, it should allocate memory for one structure and set `head->next` to NULL.

The variable `current` is a mess, e.g. you set `current->next = NULL` and two lines later set `current = current->next`. To make the code work, you need two variables, I would call them `tail` and `current`. `tail` should point to the last node in the linked list. So initially, `tail` points to `head`. When you create a new node, the code should look like this

```
    current = (wordNode*)malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
    current->word = strdup( nextWord );
    current->next = NULL;
    tail->next = current;
    tail = current;
```

Also, don't check `fscanf` for `EOF`. Instead, check that `fscanf` returns the expected number of conversions. The reason is that `fscanf` could get stuck in an infinite loop if a conversion fails before the end-of-file is reached. So the `while` loop should be

```
while(fscanf(input, "%11s", nextWord) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not saving the input. Only their addresses saving in the linked list.

When you assinged `head->word = nextWord` the address of the `nextWord` which is a local aray is assigning.

You need to enough space in the struct like `char Word[SIZE]` or use dynamic allocation `char *Word = malloc( SIZE )` and you should use strcpy to copy the input.

```
head->word = malloc(SIZE);
strcpy(heap->word, nextWord);
```

Also there is a little mistake

```
        wordNode *head = malloc(sizeof(wordNode));
        head->next = malloc(sizeof(wordNode)); /* (1) Allocated */
        head->word = nextWord;

        printf("%s ", head->word);
        wordNode *current = head->next; /* current points allocated memory (1) */

    //Begin Iteration
        while(fscanf(input, "%s", nextWord) != EOF)
        {
            current = (wordNode*)malloc(sizeof(wordNode)); /*re-allocation 
and (1) is allocated but not used memory you can not access it anymore*/
            current->word = nextWord;
            current->next = NULL;
            printf("%s ", current->word);
            current = current->next;
       }

        printList(head);
     }
```